# How to order parts of mutlipart mms when sending programmaticaly

Tags: android, mms

i have problems to order parts of mms the way i want. The problem is that text is always after iamges but i don't want this. I tried the content type parameter level but it did not have results. In fact, I don't know what does it serve because i can't find anything on wap documentation about most of the parameters. Is there a way to order body parts ? Thanks.

Comment: I havent programmed relating to MMS in years - but all the phones I've used (Samsung, Huawei (On T-Mobile)) always put the text after the image even when sending manually from the phone.  Even if you add text, then add a picture - the text gets moved to bottom.  I tried googling for your dilemma but didnt find anything useful - possibly it depends on manufacturer or carrier?

Comment: How the app textra did then. it's like they are sending the parts separetly but it arrives as the same multipart mms at the end.

Comment: Do you think using hierarchy of multipart related or mixed with text and image can do the trick. (2 level of multipart).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can try this:

```
SOAP attachment : multipart /related 
-----part 1 
-----multipart/mixed 
    -------------part 1 
    -------------part 2 
    -------------part 3
```

The inner MIME part can be multipart/mixed or multipart/related.

Multipart/related is used if a SMIL presentation is present.

Multipart/mixed is used if no SMIL presentation is present.

[See](http://www.openmobilealliance.org/release/MMS/V1_1-20021104-C/OMA-IOP-MMSCONF-V2_0_0-20020206-C.pdf) the section at 6.4

I've also come across some more concrete [examples](https://www.nowsms.com/sending-mms-messages-with-nowsms) courtesy of NowSMS (the aggregator shouldnt matter) - but keep in mind it looks like the MMSC has to support it as well.

> The “Content-type:” header in the POST should be one of the “multipart” types (usually “multipart/related”), and should include a “boundary=” parameter that delimits the different parts of the message.
>
> The first part of the multipart message is expected to be the XML for the MM7 request, and we’re going to expect to see a section with at least one , or recipient specified.
>
> The second part of the multipart message is expected to be the content for the MMS message, and this in turn will usually be another MIME multipart structure.
>
> The following example is adapted from the official MM7 specification that is included in the 3GPP TS 23.140 specification:
>
> Note that this example does not include a SMIL file, and as part of the MMS content, you would probably want to include a SMIL file (application/smil), which this example does not include.
>
> Also note that the MM7 XML portion of the document (the first part of the main multipart content) should not use any Content-Transfer-Encoding, it should always be expressed without any encoding. For the portion of the document that includes the MMS content itself, you can use Content-Transfer-Encoding of either quoted-printable or base64, or no encoding can be specified in which case it is assumed that the binary data is to be included as is.

Their example is (and sorry the XML is not properly formatted):

```
POST /mm7 HTTP/1.1
Host: mms.omms.com
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=”NextPart_000_0028_01C19839.84698430″; type=text/xml; start=”</tnn-200102/mm7-submit>”
Content-Length: nnnn
SOAPAction: “”

–NextPart_000_0028_01C19839.84698430
Content-Type:text/xml; charset=”utf-8″
Content-ID: </tnn-200102/mm7-submit>

<?xml version=”1.0″ ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env=”http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/”>
<env:Header>
<mm7:TransactionID xmlns:mm7=”http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-M M7-1-3″ env:mustUnderstand=”1″>
vas00001-sub
</mm7:TransactionID>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
<SubmitReq xmlns=”http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-3″>
<MM7Version>5.6.0</MM7Version>
<SenderIdentification>
<VASPID>TNN</VASPID>
<VASID>News</VASID>
</SenderIdentification>
<Recipients>
<To>
<Number>7255441234</Number>
</To>
<Cc>
<Number>7255443333</Number>
</Cc>
<Bcc>
<RFC2822Address>7255444444@OMMS.com</RFC2822Address>
</Bcc>
</Recipients>
<ServiceCode>gold-sp33-im42</ServiceCode>
<LinkedID>mms00016666</LinkedID>
<MessageClass>Informational</MessageClass>
<TimeStamp>2002-01-02T09:30:47-05:00</TimeStamp>
<EarliestDeliveryTime>2002-01-02T09:30:47-05:00</EarliestDeliveryTime>
<ExpiryDate>P90D</ExpiryDate>
<DeliveryReport>true</DeliveryReport>
<Priority>Normal</Priority>
<Subject>News for today</Subject>
<ChargedParty>Sender</ChargedParty>
<DistributionIndicator>true</DistributionIndicator>
<Content href=”cid:SaturnPics-01020930@news.tnn.com” allowAdaptations=”true”/>
</SubmitReq>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
–NextPart_000_0028_01C19839.84698430
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=”StoryParts-74526-8432-2002-77645″
Content-ID:SaturnPics-01020930@news.tnn.com

–StoryParts-74526-8432-2002-77645
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=”us-ascii”

Science news, new Saturn pictures…
–StoryParts-74526-8432-2002-77645
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-ID:<saturn.gif>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
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–StoryParts 74526-8432-2002-77645–
–NextPart_000_0028_01C19839.84698430–
```

> This is just a quick example of an MM7 connection to help you get started.
>
> Note that in the above example, the binary data for the image has been base64 encoded. This is not necessary when submitting MMS messages to NowSMS using MM7. The standard 8-bit binary data can be included in the MIME object without encoding.

Comment: Did this answer help cilies?

Comment: It helped me but i will try to resolve this issue later at the end of my coding. I think it should work but it will make my code more complicated.

Comment: I hope it works for you - if it does - please dont forget to accept the answer!  Good luck!

Comment: I think i will let this cos i tried to compose the pdu but it's not well documented. I don't know if i have to do like other parts put headerLength + dataLength(header of part + datalength part ?) + content type length. If i have to put Part Content type 0x91 header field. Should i put number of mutlipart mixed or number of mulitpart mixed + number of parts within before all parts and after content type ? It's complicated i will try several possibilites.

Comment: IMHO, I wouldnt think you'd need to mess with the PDU in anyway, thats super low level (and hard!) There should be a simple way to do it on android - I did read that MMS on android goes over data and not to a MMSC as compared to SMS - but what I read could be completely wrong.  Keep us posted of your findings! Good luck.

Comment: no for replacing default messaging app that's the way to do with bytes...  i have to put n Entries data length... But it works wihtout ordering. I would i have liked to do this but nevermind thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome!  If you need to deal with PDU's check out PDUSpy - its a very handy PDU tool.  While my answer didnt 100% help you out, I think it might have if you were doing plain old MMS - do you want to accept the answer just so it doesnt show as unanswered?

Comment: Thanks for the tool i'll try with this . I'll keep you informed.

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad you got it going and I could help a bit!